# Understanding Python dictionary "lookups" between dictionaries to replace keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and my objective was to replace the keys in first_dict, with the values in second_dict.

I got the code working, but largely through trial and error, so would like some help understanding and translate exactly what is going on here in Python.

```
first_dict={"FirstName": "Jeff", "Town": "Birmingham"}
second_dict={"FirstName": "c1", "Town": "c2"}
new_dict = {second_dict[k]: v for k, v in first_dict.items()}
```

This gives me what I want, a new dict as follows:

```
{'c1': 'Jeff', 'c2': 'Birmingham'}
```

How is this working?

- "new_dict" creates a new dictionary
- so "in first_dict.items()", i.e. for each key-value paid in "first_dict":
- the value in the new_dict is the value from "row"
- the key in the new_dict is the value from the second_dict

How does "second_dict[k]" do this? it seems like it is doing some sort of a lookup to match between the keys of first_dict and second_dict? Is this right, and if so, how does it work?

Comment: Because the hash of "FirstName" (a key in first_dict and a str object) is the same everywhere.

Comment: So you are asking how dictionaries work?

Comment: YouYou should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are implemented using hash tables. It is basically an array. To access the array we need indices. The indices are obtained using a hash function on the keys. Hash function tries to distribute the key evenly (property of any hash function - hash functions hate collisions).

When you are creating the last dictionary, it just reads the `k` and `v` from the other dictionary and then the value `v`'s become the key of the new dictionary. So yes, the hash function finds out the hashed values and then in that index put the correct value (which is `k` from other dictionary for you).

Note: How a hashtable handles collision is a separate topic in itself. There are several ways of handling this. One of them is open addressing scheme. You can look that up for further details.